# Polymerjs Starter Kit: can't serve Word documents

Tags: polymer-starter-kit

I am using the Polymer Starter Kit to build a small website.  However I have run into a problem.  I am wanting to serve up Word documents.  The usual way is to place these in an anchor tag eg

```
<a href="../materials/Session1.docx">Session Notes</a>
```

However this is captured as a page to load by Polymer and produces the 404 page, though the url on the page is correct.  When I refresh the page, the document is served up normally.

How can I adjust the starter kit, especially the _pageChanged function so that there is no page change and the normal process of simply serving the document is followed.

Edit:

I have solved the problem, however not using anchor tags.  I created a small form component with simply a button.  In the form I have two fields which become attributes, one for the form action attribute and one for the button text.  This means that in my pages I simply call this component with two attributes

```
<form-button submit="Button text" action="file location"></form-button>
```

While not the most elegant solution it has the desired effect.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to find a CDN or use a Cloud-based solution. You could, for example, use Google Drive and find a sharelink to direct link converter and have it served externally.

Another method, harder, would be to set up another web server on a different port. For example, NGINX running on Port 80, with the PSK running, and Apache running on port 81, serving your Word Documents. Not as convenient, but it would work.

Comment: Thanks for your suggesting, I found another solution see above.